# Dataflow subdag parallel job when orchestrated by Airflow Master Dag does not populate SQL Server table

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I have Master Dag which orchestrates bunch of API subdag Dataflow ingestion job and data load subdag job from gcs to sql server ( 7 api and 7 sql server). Master Dag simply triggers sub dags and has Dagsensor which pokes for successful dag run. If it is not successful the next subdag in line does not execute.

```
Dagsensor(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='status_check_abcd',
        external_dag_id='ABCD_DF',
        poke interval=30,
        timeout=4000,

task1_pipeline >> [trigger_dag_Abcd, status_check_abcd]
```

Issue is when the Master Dag triggers the API dataflow subdag it executes fine and creates csv file in GCS bucket. Next for the next set of 7 subdag the task is to pull the file and load into sql server. The task for 7 dataflow sql server job are set in parallel in Composer.

The Master Dag executes all the sql server successfully and is confirmed in dataflow .
But sometimes out of the 7 csv files only 2 gets loaded. If I execute the task manually to load sql server job it is fine.

Not sure why the sql server api dataflow job gets executed in Master Dag in parallel.

Is the Dag sensor the cause  ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, do you have access to airflow UI? have you try left debugging messages of the amount of records you load? Can you detail your code? to me it looks like task1_pipeline is your master activity and both trigger,status are your childs... or this is just one dag??. Also, on dataflow side when you said is confirmed, it shows the amount of records you pass?. About your manual process, can you detail the steps on your question?

Comment: Hi, Dataflow job shows that the csv file is generated and I could confirm it by the status json message generated by the code . I am using Master Dag to trigger subdag  which are individual Dataflow job. Locally I pass the same dataflow parameters to the code and execute it using local runner which writes the data into sql table. As mentioned when I run the job individually from UI it executes successfully.

Comment: Then it means that there is no issue with the job, but the parameters that are sending from your dag to the job. Maybe you are sending the same values (ie dag1-> file1.csv dag2->file1.csv, dag3->file1.csv) to the individuals dataflow job and thats why you are only seeing the same values when you upload. I would like to know more details to replicate your issue on my side like the code you use to upload to dataflow. the full dag job, if possible.